# UIButton and UILabel display strange characters when reading from sqlite

Tags: ios, uilabel

my app reading from a SQLite database and display the text on UILabel, but for some reasons, a small "rectangle symbol" appear as shown  in the picture. When I use NSLog to print the text in the console, the text appears normally, i.e, just printing out "Home." (without the rectangle symbol)

[image]

Here is my code:

```
NSString *text=[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];

NSLog(text);
myLabel.text=text;
```

Comment: Maybe the encoding of the SQL table is not UTF-8?

Comment: It can be, how can I set it up UTF-8?

Comment: I just check out my DB setting, it is encoded with UTF-8

Comment: hm - strange problem, indeed!

Comment: perhaps your string is terminated with CR/LF characters?

Comment: @CSmith: it also appears at some places within a text sentence

Comment: when logging the text sentence, are you seeing the line "broken" at these points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
NSLog ([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s<--",text]);
```

in your console output, does the <-- appear on the line below the text?  If so, you've likely got a CR/LF terminated string.

Or likely more useful, enumerate each character in your string and output to console as hex value, you can then at least see what these characters are (if not CR/LF).

Comment: do you mean this one `NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s***",text]);`? Because Xcode gives error with your code

Comment: doh, Android/iOS oops.  Yes, exactly!  Sorry  Will edit my answer

Comment: I copied text from PC, added to SQlite DB in MAC, so some special characters are hidden in MAC